# Tiempos de ejecución de algoritmo C++ vs python

Tags: python, c++, eficiencia

Estoy analizando empíricamente los tiempos de ejecución para el mismo algoritmo (calcular el subarreglo máximo de un arreglo) en python y C++. La sorpresa es que en python los tiempos de ejecución son considerablemente más altos que en C++.
¿A qué puede ser debido estas grandes diferencias? ¿Quizás porque python es interpretado?

Dejo los códigos de los algoritmos en ambos lenguajes y los tiempos de ejecución de ambos para un conjunto de vectores con diferentes tamaños. El algoritmo en C++ lo lanzo mediante un script que automatiza X lanzamientos y guarda el resultado en un archivo .dat. En python lo hago todo en el mismo .py por comodidad.

Python

```
#Función para calcular el subarreglo máximo
def sum_mayor(fin,T):
    start = 0
    finish = 0
    max_sum = 0

    for i in range(0,fin):
        sum_aux = 0
        for j in range(i,fin):
            sum_aux +=  T[j]
            if sum_aux > max_sum:
                start = i
                finish = j
                max_sum = sum_aux

    return start, finish, max_sum



if __name__ == '__main__':

    T = []
    # Generador de vector de aleatorios
    for i in range(5000,200000,5000):
        T.clear()
        for j in range(0,i):
            T.append(int(random.uniform(-50,50)))
            
            
        n = len(T)
        with open('salida_fuerzabruta_python.dat', 'a') as f:
            start_time = time.time()
            index_left, index_right, max_sum = sum_mayor(n-1, T)
            finish_time = time.time()
            total_time = finish_time - start_time
            f.write(str(i)+'\t' + str(total_time)+'\n')
```

C++

```
// Función para calcular el subarreglo máximo 
pair<int,int> sum_mayor(int fin, int T[]){

    pair<int,int> indices_maxsum;
    int max_sum = 0;
    int sum_aux = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<fin;i++){
        sum_aux = 0;
        for(int j=i;j<fin;j++){
            sum_aux = sum_aux+T[j];
            if(sum_aux > max_sum){
                indices_maxsum.first = i;
                indices_maxsum.second = j;
                max_sum = sum_aux;
            }
        }
    }
    return indices_maxsum;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      cerr << "Formato " << argv[0] << " <num_elem>" << endl;
      return -1;
    }

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int * T = new int[n];
    assert(T);

    srand(time(0));
    // Generar vector de enteros random entre -50 y 50
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        double u = -50+rand()%(51-(-50));
        T[j]= (int) (u);
    }
    high_resolution_clock::time_point tantes, tdespues;
    duration<double> transcurrido;
    // Tomar tiempo al inicio
    tantes = high_resolution_clock::now();
    pair<int,int> maxsum_cuadratico = sum_mayor(n-1,T);
    // Tomar tiempo al final
    tdespues = high_resolution_clock::now();
    transcurrido = duration_cast<duration<double>>(tdespues-tantes);
    // Guardar el resultado en un .dat mediante un script de bash independiente
    cout << argv[1] << "\t" << transcurrido.count() << endl;
}
```

Salida del algoritmo en C++

Cantidad_elementos_vector - Tiempo_ejecución

```
5000    0.023376
10000   0.0733
15000   0.164317
20000   0.294064
25000   0.470664
30000   0.674484
35000   0.918896
40000   1.20797
45000   1.51965
50000   1.88458
55000   2.29065
60000   2.7311
65000   3.20941
70000   3.71479
75000   4.24886
80000   4.85419
85000   5.47363
90000   6.12998
95000   7.02149
100000  7.74754
105000  8.43045
110000  9.36553
115000  10.0744
120000  11.0353
125000  12.1959
130000  13.4107
135000  14.4251
140000  15.6673
145000  16.5153
150000  18.0961
155000  19.4227
160000  20.1816
165000  21.9428
170000  23.1083
175000  23.9729
180000  25.2035
185000  26.4413
190000  27.9625
195000  29.4232
200000  31.2388
```

Salida del algoritmo en Python
Para el algoritmo en python pongo únicamente los primeros valores, ya que se puede apreciar la grandísima diferencia en las primeras ejecuciones.

Cantidad_elementos_vector - Tiempo_ejecución

```
5000    0.5176916122436523
10000   2.073040008544922
15000   4.7448132038116455
20000   8.469029903411865
25000   14.260041952133179
30000   20.91342830657959
35000   27.943927526474
40000   34.87288022041321
45000   45.734419107437134
```

Para lanzar el algoritmo en C++ lo hago mediante el siguiente script en bash

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "" >> salida_fuerzabruta.dat
i=5000
while [ $i -le 200000 ]
do
    ./fuerzabruta $i >> salida_fuerzabruta.dat
    let i=$i+5000
done
```

Comment: Ahora analiza los tiempos y costos de desarrollo y depuración.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> La sorpresa es que en python los tiempos de ejecución son considerablemente más altos que en C++. ¿A qué puede ser debido estas grandes diferencias? ¿Quizás porque python es interpretado?

Si, es por ser interpretado. Y no es ninguna sorpresa, cualquier lenguaje interpretado es potencialmente más lento que cualquier lenguaje compilado.

Esto no hace que los lenguajes interpretados sean peores y los compilados mejores, cada aproximación tiene sus ventajas y desventajas que deben ser evaluadas en cada caso de uso; por ejemplo, en general se considera que:

|  | Lenguaje compilado | Lenguaje interpretado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tiempo de desarrollo | Alto | Bajo |
| Versatilidad frente a cambios | Alta | Baja |
| Rendimiento | Alto | Bajo |

Así pues, en un contexto en que el rendimiento de la aplicación no es clave pero se requiere cambiar el código con frecuencia, un lenguaje interpretado podría ser mejor opción que uno compilado.

---

Por otro lado, incluso dentro de los lenguajes compilados puedes encontrar notables diferencias, por ejemplo: si ejecutas el mismo algoritmo con y sin optimizaciones de compilación podrás notar diferencias en el rendimiento. Yo lo he probado con este código equivalente al tuyo:

```
std::pair<int,int> sum_mayor(int fin, int T[])
{
    std::pair<int,int> indices_maxsum;
    int max_sum = 0;
    int sum_aux = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < fin; ++i) {
        sum_aux = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < fin; ++j) {
            sum_aux = sum_aux + T[j];
            if (sum_aux > max_sum) {
                indices_maxsum.first = i;
                indices_maxsum.second = j;
                max_sum = sum_aux;
            }
        }
    }
    return indices_maxsum;
}


int main()
{
    constexpr auto size = 200000;
    int T[size]{};

    std::random_device device;
    std::mt19937 generator(device());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(-50, 50);

    std::generate_n(T, size, [&distrib, &generator]() { return distrib(generator); });
 
    // Tomar tiempo al inicio
    using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    const auto tantes = clock::now();
    const std::pair<int,int> maxsum_cuadratico = sum_mayor(size - 1, T);
    // Tomar tiempo al final
    const auto tdespues = clock::now();
    const auto transcurrido = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(tdespues - tantes);
    // Guardar el resultado en un .dat mediante un script de bash independiente
    std::cout << maxsum_cuadratico.first << ' ' << maxsum_cuadratico.second << ' ' << transcurrido.count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Sin optimizaciones ha resultado en:

> ```
> 55.7221
> ```

[Con optimizaciones ha resultado en](https://tio.run/##dVNdb9owFH1OfsWVJnWJGlraqZoKWV73uBfeKhS5toHLEjvyx9at4q@PXTsGysqAKPjc73OP@TBMeMfUer//gIp3XkioUVtnJOub/IQZpoQ@Q1i31gbd5gzkG6OVbvLcOjGbDQxNjcpV9DRgfd/27Jc2BR1hhaqC8GfxtCzz1zy7EIFKIJeWol4oeJ5nwZ8OLZ3gC0wTEhIz/zIiebbSBmIJjAi96lBtDtfXWAJVys4CslPAlhCc0@sYsB0D3kQc/l1T49tlCM9wBcUBbg79pcDsfIabFRrrYplLViu5VoLM29F8mjXlj/Aujw/9jHTeqHc87fI8H6lCVURyKa118mUwwLzTYPG3pKT30/BJLC6eArp83QUO4zLGnbdC/qDsML7myda7u8fHT59hLZU0zNFSR3tRlgcXr5CY7VtK3gokSeGzd6hV3UA6FpOHaQUP0/JYMqWTrSoWVWyzgqer5F7B1bHcsiCCIc1/SHe0lnPYUVLIs9tbWOieGXAo@0ED64gt5KjzzFtUa@Cd5t8DwaH8KN/ZbIPrTWuk1V3suI1O80TjSKFjyklLgdE2myn9syiPLhfEPC6n5Z4J6hG5Tlsdr0TcyATuKliELBfaJkWy7rwFIe3g/9/E6ERbtNwbg0L/O6bwoZMwH7OuvmiqhfbPnWya4lhtkmZPfX71zAjqVHa0Dus7x6iQVOAV3AhGIpQCg38ALDc4OJISPDO7CbqVgyTxSrInBXDtHdT1e7rS1SHTR/pe9EjX5@TydvgbyqwcyYbwWIkKd0F4SUR0D3b7/R@@6tja7iff/gI):

> ```
> 19.0694
> ```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Dudaba que fuese por eso. Ya he leído con un poco más de profundidad y ahora lo entiendo todo. Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: También puedes encontrar lenguajes que toman lo mejor de ambos mundos como Java. Que es un lenguaje que se compila pero a bytecode y funciona en la máquina virtual de Java. Lo que permite que sea multiplataforma, siempre que haya una JVM para tu sistema operativo con la arquitectura correspondiente.

Comment: No me parece que un lenguaje que compila a bytecode tenga ninguna de las ventajas de un lenguaje interpretado; está más cercano a los lenguajes compilados que a los interpretados.